# Ruby testing results of a loop

Tags: ruby, loops, testing, rspec

Quick testing question i have a FizzBuzz implementation,

```
def fizzbuzz(n)
  (1..n).each do |num|
    string = ''
    string << 'Fizz' if num % 3 == 0
    string << 'Buzz' if num % 5 == 0
    string << 'Boom' if num % 7 == 0
    string = num if string.empty?
    puts string
  end
end
```

I would like to write a test for it:

```
it 'should return the word Fizz for a number divisible by 3' do 
  expect(Thing.fizzbuzz(3)).to eq ("Fizz")
end
```

And i got

```
 Failure/Error: expect(@thing.fizzbuzz(3)).to eq ("Fizz")

   expected: "Fizz"
        got: 1..3
```

Now i know the actual result is more like

```
1
2 
'fizz'
```

But it got me thinking how i would write this so it would be easy to test?
I could shovel each instance into an array and then test specific locations, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

Your current method is `puts`ing the value to STDOUT. That makes it hard to test. Change your method to return the values as an array instead. Then test that array.

Something like this:

```
def fizzbuzz(n)
  (1..n).map do |num|
    # logic here...
    string
  end
end
```

And your test becomes this:

```
expect(@thing.fizzbuzz(3)).to eq [1, 2, "Fizz"]
```

Or maybe this:

```
expect(@thing.fizzbuzz(3)[2]).to eq "Fizz"
```

Comment: Thats what i was thinking, its better this way i suppose. Ill use your second suggestion for times when its like `fizzbuzz(105)`